# How do I get my to only update whats selected?

Tags: php, html

There are two rows in my table called post. After pressing the button the  table updates the row above it and if I click it again it updates that one it's supposed to.

If you press the button it adds 1 to the column. There are two rows, if you click the button for row 2 it will add one to row 1 then if you click it again it will update row 2. Or if you press it for one and try to press it for the other it will update the last one you clicked first and then update the one you wanted it to do.

```
//The loop echos the row out below
foreach($dbData as $post){
<form method="post" id="liketest" class="redirect" >
     <button type="submit" form = "liketest"  name="like" value= "'.$post["id"].'">

     </button> 
</form>

//If you press the button it is supposed to grab the id from the "post" (so the row id) and update count by adding 1

if (isset($_POST['like'])){
    $post_id = $_POST['like'];
    $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM likedpost");
        if($result->num_rows == 0) {
            $n = "count";
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE posts SET count = $n+1 WHERE id = $post_id ;");
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
        }

    }
```

I expect it to update the row you clicked, but the actual result is it updating the row above it then the one you clicked.

Comment: $n = "count"; ?

Comment: I do not understand your question. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

You are violating the uniqueness of an element ID when you have a loop that doesn't generate a dynamic ID. So when you reference a different form with the `form` attribute, it will not know which one to use. Just drop the `form` references on your buttons altogether.

You should also be using bounded placeholders when you're using a prepared statement.

```
foreach ($dbData as $post){
    echo '<form method="post" class="redirect" >
        <button type="submit" name="like" value= "'.$post["id"].'">
            Like this post!
        </button> 
    </form>';
} 

if (isset($_POST['like'])){
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE posts SET count = count + 1 WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['like']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['like'])) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM likedpost";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($count > 0) {
        //performed you query
    }
}

$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM likedpost";
$dbData=mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
foreach ($dbData as $post) {
    ?>
    <form method="post" id="liketest" class="redirect">
        <button type="submit" form = "liketest"  name="like" value="<?php echo $post['id']; ?>">Submit</button>
    </form>
<?php
}
```

This is simple logic you can apply in $count variable you will get number of liked post and after that you can used that $count variable count+1 to update in another table (this is mysqli Procedural way)